# Is there a way to perform jenkins maven release build from command line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

Apologies, if this is a stupid idea. I would like to check if there is a way to perform maven release build from command line. I would like to check if there is a way, even if, maven release is not meant to perform that way.

I have verified jenkins-cli.jar options. It is not available with that. Is there any alternative, to peform the release build from command line with proper autherization.? using groovy or any other option.

Please help me.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly - do you mean triggering a job execution from command line?
You can do that with REST - so if this is the case - definitely yes.

Comment: I meant maven release. How to perform that from rest call.?

Comment: Again.. not very clear what you mean by "Maven release" - its a bit vague.. I assume you wish to trigger a Jenkins job via script.
You can do that by enabling job's "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" under "Build Triggers", and set a token (or leave blank). You will then get a link you can send a simple web request to.
Example in Powershell: "Invoke-WebRequest http://JENKINS_URL/jobs/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN_NAME"